# Who ate my cookies? They are showing up neither in headers nor in cookiestore. I'm trying to read cookies from the http response

Tags: java, cookies, cookiestore

I'm trying get to the cookies from http response. But I'm getting empty output . I checked with fiddler, the http response contains a set-cookie header. But it seems that Cookies are not present in cookie store. Clearly Im going somewhere.  Where I need to correct the code ? Please help me out .

```
public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.angelvestgroup.com/info.php?id=1");
        CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
         manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);

        CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = conn.getHeaderFields();

        Set<String> headerFieldsSet = headerFields.keySet();
        Iterator<String> hearerFieldsIter = headerFieldsSet.iterator();

        while (hearerFieldsIter.hasNext()) {

         String headerFieldKey = hearerFieldsIter.next();

         if ("Set-Cookie".equalsIgnoreCase(headerFieldKey)) {

             List<String> headerFieldValue=headerFields.get(headerFieldKey);

             for (String headerValue : headerFieldValue) {

                System.out.println("Cookie Found...");

                String[] fields = headerValue.split(";\\s*");

                String cookieValue = fields[0];
                String expires = null;
                String path = null;
                String domain = null;
                boolean secure = false;

                // Parse each field
                for (int j = 1; j < fields.length; j++) {
                    if ("secure".equalsIgnoreCase(fields[j])) {
                        secure = true;
                    }
                    else if (fields[j].indexOf('=') > 0) {
                        String[] f = fields[j].split("=");
                        if ("expires".equalsIgnoreCase(f[0])) {
                            expires = f[1];
                        }
                        else if ("domain".equalsIgnoreCase(f[0])) {
                            domain = f[1];
                        }
                        else if ("path".equalsIgnoreCase(f[0])) {
                            path = f[1];
                        }
                    }

                }

                System.out.println("cookieValue:" + cookieValue);
                System.out.println("expires:" + expires);
                System.out.println("path:" + path);
                System.out.println("domain:" + domain);
                System.out.println("secure:" + secure);

                        System.out.println("*****************************************");

                 CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();

                 List <HttpCookie> cookies =
                        cookieJar.get(url.toURI());
                    for (HttpCookie cookie: cookies) {
                      System.out.println("CookieHandler retrieved cookie: " + cookie);
                    }
             }

         }

    }

}

 }
```

Comment: "Who ate my cookies?" I like that... :-D

Comment: Yep, cant do without humor. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps boring and without humor, but with better indentation it would be easier for us to spot certain programming errors and to help you fix your problem. Most tools can fix indentation automatically

Comment: sorry about that, I was in hurry.

Answer (score 0):

My first ever question at Stack turns out to be a bug in the Java version being used. 
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8160038